# Python:How to pick adjacent elements?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape (https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Remember_the_Titans#Coach_Boone), I want get quotes from all sections but Dialogue, Taglines and External Links. I can go to `ul > li` but then it is fetching everything. How can I fetch `ul > li` after the following html:

```
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Coach_Boone">Coach Boone</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a href="/w/index.php?title=Remember_the_Titans&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Edit section: Coach Boone">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've located the `h2` element, use [`.find_next_siblings()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) method to get the following `ul` sibling elements:

```
h2 = soup.find("span", id="Coach_Boone").find_parent('h2')
for ul in h2.find_next_siblings("ul"):
    for li in ul.find_all("li"):
        print(li)
```

Comment: The only issue I find that it fetches `ul` of next sections as well.